# @RefereshScope in Spring config server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

As per the documentation whenever the bean in `RefereshScope` and the actuator end-point refresh called the bean got refreshed.

Questions :

1. Bean refresh means spring load the bean again?
2. If Spring load the bean again and A bean is in a refresh-Scope and B bean contains reference of A, Will the system again load the Bean B.
3. If I marked all beans as `@RefereshScope`(all beans having `@value` attribute), Is it similar to server startup.